# How do I set the JDK in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Downloaded the Oracle XE and Oracle SQL Developer to my home computer (Windows) to learn PL/SQL.  I use PL/SQL Developer at work but never set it up.

I downloaded the Oracle SQL Developer and all went well with the download.  Got it working in the application view but when trying to run the sqldeveloper.sh I get errors showing up on the screen.  The error reads:

```
The JDK 'C:Program' is not a valid JDK
The JDK specified by the SetJavaHome directive in 
/c/../../.sqldeveloper/21.1.4.1/product.conf

Type the full pathnmae of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will 
be stored in /c/../../.sqldeveloper/21.1.4.1/product.conf
```

I opened the product.conf file and added:

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
```

and did not work, so changed the directives from '' to '/'

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java9.0.4\jdk
```

and still does not work.  I even uninstall the version I downloaded first with without the jre and downloaded and installed the version that came with the jdk 8.  I read through the post on stackoverflow and tried the solutions but nothing.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

A couple of items to note:

To launch SQL Developer in Windows, you will want to launch sqldeveloper.**exe**, not sqldeveloper.**sh**

When you go to the [SQL Developer Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html), if you download **Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included** you will not need to specify the path to your Java installation because it will come bundled with the installation.

If you choose to download **Windows 32-bit/64-bit**, you will then be prompted for the path to your JDK home when you first launch SQL Developer so you do not need to edit any configuration files or environment variables.

Comment: I am running it in Windows.  My sqldeveloper.exe works, but not the sqldeveloper.sh.  I thought the sqldeveloper.sh was the cmd of sqldeveloper?  Only had one option for the newest version of sqldeveloper, which was Window32/-bit/64-bit. How would I run sqldeveloper in command line view?  Thanks

Comment: sqldeveloper.bat is what you would use from cmd prompt in windows. if you want a command line view, use SQLcl (sql.exe in the bin directory)

Comment: sqldeveloper.exe is used to launch on windows, sqldeveloper.sh is used to launch on Linux. What do you mean run command line view? If you are trying to launch SQLcl, the sql.exe executable is found in the bin directory of the installation.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking that bash was linux dir